# Should I used vapor barrier for floor?

Tags: insulation

Please consider the following layers, bottom to top, for my small cabin:

1. Large wooden construction beams, raised from the soil (laid horizontally, on top of treated wooden posts)
2. Breathable membrane sheet stapled to the beams
3. Floor joists, laid in 40cm spaces from each other
4. Rockwool insulation, sits on top of the breathable membrane, in the space between the floor joists
5. OSB boards
6. Wooden tounge and groove floor

The outside environmnet can get relatively cold and humid.

Do I need a vapor barrier sheet somewhere between these layers ?

Thank you

Comment: Side note: If your cabin is located somewhere that is vulnerable to pests, you may want to put some sort of mesh or boarding on the underside of that membrane to avoid the rockwool becoming a home to all sorts of lovely animals. Breather membrane is really just fancy paper and they waste little time ripping into it.

Comment: @LukeBriggs are you talking about big animals like rodents ? Or ants / termites etc ?

Comment: all of the above, but mainly the ones with tails and fur :) I have PIR (rigid insulation) under a suspended floor here and it has been occasionally scratched at by local cats and squirrels but nothing damaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, an insulated timber building in a cold climate zone should have a vapour barrier on the warm side of the insulation, including on a suspended timber floor.**

In a colder [climate zone](https://basc.pnnl.gov/images/iecc-climate-zone-map) like the one referenced in the question the vapour barrier generally protects the timbers from **you**. That's because showering, sweating, cooking etc produces lots of vapour which ultimately has to go somewhere.

Water vapour, like air in general, goes from high to low density to balance out. It largely doesn't care which direction it is in either. Cold dry air outside means the vapour wants to go outwards, and it'll go down through the floor if it can. When it passes through insulation it goes through the dew point where it then condenses to form mold loving droplets. Your goal is to prevent that to create a substantial increase in a buildings service lifetime as well as efficiency gains because warm air escaping is ultimately wasted energy too.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Would you put the vapour barrier on top of the rockwool, under the OSB boards ? i.e. between #4 and #5 in my layers I specified in the question ? Also, would faced rockwool (facing up) serve as a vapour barrier ? What would happen to the droplets accumulating there then ?

Comment: @Michael correct, it goes under the OSB. Foil facings do work as a barrier yes,  provided you can tape all of the gaps which is a pretty fiddley process (and foil tape is also quite pricey, at least here in the UK anyway!). As it's the warm side of the insulation the drops essentially don't form directly under the OSB.

Answer (score 1):

Ventilate the crawl-space such that it stays dry, or if that is impossible,
lay plastic sheeting on the ground.

Comment: The crawl space is ventilated as the platform is raised from the ground, I will lay gardening sheet (one that lets water through, not sure what's the name of it) on the ground so that weed doesn't grow anyway, but will that be enough ? And are they layers I specified seem okay ?

Comment: "Gardening sheet", @Michael, is usually called "landscape fabric".